# Jinja templating a Json GraphQL Query via Ansible URI module

Tags: json, ansible, graphql, jinja2, uri

I'm trying to query the AuditLog Github provides via their [API](https://api.github.com/graphql) using ansible uri module, and having difficulty wrapping my head around JSON formatting within ansible.

So I have this working GraphQL query, but I want to turn the 'created:' query into a variable that I can change on a daily/hourly basis.

```
  organization(login: "my_org_here") {
    auditLog(last: 100, query: "created:>=2019-07-22") {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on AuditEntry {
            action
            actorLogin
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I cannot fathom how to write this in ansible yaml format.  Here's what I've tried:

```
  uri:
    url: https://api.github.com/graphql
    headers:
      Authorization: 'Bearer MY_TOKEN_HERE'
      Accept: 'application/vnd.github.audit-log-preview+json'
    method: POST
    body: " {{ lookup('template','files/auditlog.json.j2') }}"
    body_format: json
```

Contents of the auditlog.json.j2:

```
query:
  organization:
    login: my_org_here
    auditlog:
      last: 100
      query: {{ query_variable }}
```

Essentially, I'd like to be able to really take apart the entire GraphQL query item by item and parameterize each component.  But I'm stuck trying to recreate the GraphQL JSON via ansible.  Here's a working JSON example (with more fields in the detail I'm looking to obtain):

```
"query": "{\n  organization(login: \"my_org_here\") {\n    auditLog(last: 100, query: \"created:>=2019-07-20\") {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          ... on AuditEntry {\n            action\n            actorLogin\n            \n            createdAt\n            actorIp\n            userLogin\n            user {\n              name\n              email\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n"
```

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking how to generate a GraphQL in jinja2, which should be straightforward, or if you erroneously think that GraphQL **is JSON** which it certainly is not. Your example file `auditlog.json.j2` does not contain JSON, either, it looks like YAML; what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: I essentially want to write YAML, have it go through Jinja templating to become JSON, and make it look / work in an ansible uri module / call to Github's graphql endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of the GitHub GraphQL query request is a JSON object with a `query` key, whose value is the GraphQL query as a string. In your example, what you are missing is the `query` key inside the `body`. Check this task as an example:

```
- name: Get data from Github
  uri:
    url: https://api.github.com/graphql
    method: POST
    headers:
      Authorization: 'bearer {{ github_token }}'
    body_format: json
    body:
      query: '{{ lookup("template", "./templates/github_query.graphql") }}'
```

Where my `./templates/github_query.graphql` file is:

```
query {
  repository(owner:"{{ owner }}", name:"{{ repository_name }}") {
    issues(last:{{ last_issues }}, states:{{ states }}) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          labels(first:{{ labels_count }}) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I can modify how the query works by modifying the `owner`, `repository_name`, `last_issues` and `labels_count` variable.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thanks so much for the lesson!